# select website at registration

Tags: magento-1.8, customer

I need to add a `<select>` for the available websites in `magento admin` at user registration page and associate that customer to the selected website. e.g., if there were 3 websites in magento viz. `Main Store`, `Other Store` and `Another Store` then user will be able to chose any one of them at registration page and associated with that particular website.

I'd been google for a long and found quite similar thing [Select Customer Group at Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12201824/725306) but that wasn't helpful to me. Can anybody have any idea on how to do this?

**What I've tried till now?**
I'd overriden the `Customer/AccountController`'s `createPostAction()` for adding the selected website in customer model. The code snippet I tried:

```
$webid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website_id');
$customer = $this->_getCustomer();
$customer->setData('website_id', $webid); //1st approach
$customer->setWebsiteId($webid); //2nd approach
//3rd approach
$customerForm = $this->_getModel('customer/form');
            $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
                    ->setEntity($customer);

//and before }
parent::createPostAction();
```

**How do I'm getting the website list?**

```
<select name="website_id" id="store_name">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <?php
    $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
    foreach ($websites as $web) {
        echo "<option value='" . $web->getId() . "'>" . $web->getName() . "</option>\n";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[finally found this answer helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309714/725306). But I'd made some changes in the observer where I do needed to get the `website id` selected by the customer.

**Here's the code from my observer**

```
public function setWebsiteId($object) {
    //getting website_id from user selection
    $webid = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()
            ->getParam('website_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    $customer = $object->getCustomer();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($webid);
    return $this;
}
```

**Update**

The event need to be handled is: `customer_register_success`

**Revision**

The above code works fine but the problem with the above implementation was, if a user is already registered in the current website then from the current website he will not be able to register in the other website. To solve this problem I'd overridden the `Customer/AccountController`'s `createPostAction()`

```
public function createPostAction() {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if (isset($post['website_id'])) {
        $webid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website_id');
        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($webid);
        Mage::register('current_customer', $customer); //this is the important line here
    }
    parent::createPostAction();
}
```

If I'm not doing this `Mage::register('current_customer', $customer);` then the parent `createPostAction()` will again fetch customer object as `$customer = $this->_getCustomer();` and loss `website_id` which I had set in there previously.

Answer (score 2):

The Another Solutions is you can override the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` Account Controller.

Also in this Controller you got one method as below

```
/**
 * Create customer account action
 */
public function createPostAction()
{
       // take whole code of this method and add your set website id code in Object.
}
```

Hope you know how to override the Class. then its very simple for you.

Comment: yeah dear! I'd tried that too but it doesn't worked...
[see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21721051/725306)

Comment: I Done this around 3 days ago Its working fine.

Comment: can you tell me how do you added the `website_id`? in request post or customer object?

Comment: because I tried both of them

Comment: you create one custom customer attribute and create one drop down at registration form and rewrite the module

Comment: I already have a `custom attribute` and its been working fine.. but the thing I need to do is to change the website to which he is associated as per his selection... I hope you understand this

Comment: no still confused

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13013/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-keyul-shah)