# redirect customer to associated website on successful registration

Tags: magento-1.8, module, customer, redirect

I'd been working on a module where customer choose at the time of registration for which website he need to register. So far I'd done it working. A [quick reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14899/4426) to that. On successful registration the customer is being redirected to `customer/account/` in the current website regardless of which website he chosen. But I need him to be redirected to that particular website for which he had registered.

So far I'd tried overriding the `Customer/AccountController`'s `_welcomeCustomer()`:

```
protected function _welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConformed = false) {
    $webid = $customer->getWebsiteId();
    $successurl = parent::_welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConfirmed);
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == $webid) {
        return $successurl;
    } else {
        return Mage::app()->getWebsite($webid)->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl() . 'customer/account/index';
    }
}
```

But instead of redirecting the customer to associated website it being redirected to home page of the current website. Any help? How could it be done? or this happening so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [auto-login module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/313180/) helped me to achieve what I'm looking for.
Rest of the thing I've done to make it work proper is:

Overridden the `Customer/AccountController`'s `_welcomeCustomer()`

```
protected function _welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConformed = false) {
    $webid = $customer->getWebsiteId();
    $encpw = ;//get customer password and encrypt it;
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == $webid) {
        return parent::_welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConfirmed);
    } else {
        $redr = Mage::app()->getWebsite($webid)->getDefaultStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl() . 'customer/account/autoLogin/'
                . 'user/' . $customer->getEmail() . '/pwd/' . $encpw .
                '/';
        return $redr;
    }
}
```

One more thing might needed to be changed in `_successProcessRegistration()` is to replace `$this->_redirectSuccess($url);` with `$this->_redirectUrl($url);` as suggested by **oleksii.svarychevskyi** [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/15048/4426)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller you can set redirect to url

```
$url = Mage::app()->getWebsite($webid)->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl() . 'customer/account/index';
$this->_redirectUrl($url);
```

Also read [this article](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-multiple-website-login) about login in a magento multiple website setup.

Comment: as I can see in `Customer/AccountController`'s `_successProcessRegistration()` from where its being called and after that it do redirect as: `$url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer); $this->_redirectSuccess($url);`

Comment: But `$this->_redirectUrl()` and `$this->_redirectSuccess()` are different functions

Comment: but I tried your solution and still the same thing. should i return this new url or not?

Comment: I recommend you to rewrite `_successProcessRegistration` instead of _welcomeCustomer. And run $this->_redirectUrl($url) instead of `$this->_redirectSuccess()` there.

Comment: okay.. now its been redirected but its been asked to login. customer must be redirected to his dashboard

Comment: Are sites' base urls different?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13042/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-oleksii-svarychevskyi)